# Manipulation of DOCX in VBA?

Tags: vba, docx

In C#/.NET I am able to open a DOCX file as a `ZipPackage`, then manipulate its XML parts separately by getting them as `PackagePart`s and reading from / writing to their `Stream`s using `.GetStream()`.

As far as I'm aware, VBA is a million miles away from having this functionality (especially given that I've not found anything about it after a lot of web searching), but I just thought I'd check: can any VBA aficionados confirm or deny whether VBA has some kind of built-in functionality for manipulating DOCX `ZipPackage`s, or would you pretty much have to write your own VBA DOCX parser from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly the answer is no, but there is a glimmmer of yes.

Regarding your specific question of managing `PackagePart`s from their streams. You could probably do this with some kind of "unzip" utility and then knowing the OPC structure, navigate to whereever you want in the `Part`s and change things with XSLT or other XML manipulation technologies - but you wouldn't be able to do this on the `ActiveDocument`because its stream is already in use by nature of it being open. You could use VBA to create a copy of it and manipulate that one in a really cumbersome manner and when your manipulation is done, have VBA close and delete the current `ActiveDocument` and open your manipulated one as the new `ActiveDocument`.

On the other hand, there is a way to manipulate WordprocessingML for the current `ActiveDocument` from VBA, but it would be incredibly difficult to do. Have an open document, select something and then to the VBE. Then run this:

```
Sub InjectXML()
    Dim wd As Document: Set wd = ActiveDocument
    Debug.Print wd.Range.WordOpenXML
End Sub
```

You'll see all the WordprocessingML spit out in the immediate window. This is actually "Flat OPC WordprocessingML" as it is all maintained in a *single* string of XML. By using `ActiveDocument.Range.InsertXML`, you could technically insert [Flat OPC-type of WordprocessingML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/the-flat-opc-format.aspx) back into the document at the selected location. [Here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranavwagh/archive/2011/06/20/manipulating-office-document-contents-_1320_-on-steroids_2100_.aspx) of someone using C# to do this via interop and Linq-to-XML. To do this in VBA would be incredibly hard.

So again, the answer is mostly "no", but a little bit of "yes".

Answer (score 0):

You do not state your ultimate aim, but I guess one possibility is to use [Microsoft.office.interop.word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx) to manipulate the word document.

Comment: Unless of course you can not afford the dependencies attached with that, in which case you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: Is that namespace available in VBA, or is it just for programs that interact with Word via COM?  I'm thinking of VBA scripting internal to Office here (actually Outlook, not Word).